# framework not found OpenGL

Tags: iphone, xcode, opengl

I have a project, that uses the OpenGL framework. In order to try to get some other aspect of the project to work,  I may have fiddled around the developer libraries (it was more then a week ago so i don't remember exactly what I did).

now when I try to build the project I get "framework not found OpenGL".

I have already uninstall xcode completely:
sudo /Developer/Library/uninstall-devtools –mode=all

and reinstalled it, but stil the same error.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Have you added the OpenGL framework to the project.  In Xcode with your project open, select "Add to Project... " from the "Project" menu.  Use the resulting dialog sheet to find the OpenGL project at

```
$ /System/Library/Frameworks/OpenGL.framework
```

A new dialog sheet will allow you to set options, make sure you don't "copy items into destination group's folder".

Comment: If you need OpenGLES.framework for an iPhone app, you can find the framework in:

/Developer/Platforms/iPhoneOS.platform/Developer/SDKs/iPhoneOS3.1.2.sdk/System/Library/Frameworks/OpenGLES.framework

In the middle of that path is "iPhone0S3.1.2.sdk".  Adjust appropriately for whichever version of iPhone OS the project is targeting.